# Error in uploading file

Tags: node.js, formidable

End user uploads a file through the web application. I use [Blueimp jQuery Fileupload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) for this.

On the server side, I use [formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable) that pipes the uploaded file to a cloud based file service that I am using.

The code is as follows -

```
//The function called when file is uploaded
function (req, res) {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req);

    form.on('file', function (name, file) {
        //Code that uploads the file to the cloud based hosting service
        //Once uploaded, we return with the response
        res.send(201, data)
    });
}
```

However, the code that uploads to cloud based hosting service takes time (depending on the file size).
What I wish to do is return immediately and not wait for the file to get uploaded to the cloud. That is, carry out the upload to cloud in the background so to say.

If I move the `res.send(201, data)` outside of the `file` event and put it at the end of the function, I get a 'Request timeout - Connection closed without response' error.

How can I carry the upload in the "background" and return immediately?

Answer (score 0):

If you use express you could probably do:

```
function (req, res, next) {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.on('file', function (name, file) { });
    form.parse(req);

    next(req, res);
}
```